# get to the label inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Can someone please show me how to get to **label1** inside the iframe via JavaScript?

**WebForm1.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="calendar">
        <iframe src="WebForm2.aspx"></iframe>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**WebForm2.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr><td class="default"><label id="label1">Label1</label></td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the iframe an Id say for example

```
<iframe src="WebForm2.aspx" id="webForm" ></iframe>
```

Then in order to gain access to the field **"lable1"** you have give the following code

```
(document.getElementById("webForm")).contentWindow.document.getElementById("label1").innerHTML;
```

Hope this helps you